# jquery inactive after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

im using jquery sortable on a list to move the elements around. It works fine to start but I also have an ajax panel on my page that can add new items to the list. Once ajax sends new elements to the list I can no-longer sort it. I have this call:

```
$("#MainContent_previewlist").sortable({
            update: function (event, ui) { }
        });
```

I am not familiar with javascript. Do I need to call some event to get jquery to evaluate the new list after ajax?

Comment: after ajax call you need to recall this

Comment: Can you please add your remaining code. a jsFiddle will help.

Comment: At the end of your ajax call function reinitialize the sortable eg -- $("#MainContent_previewlist").sortable();  -- see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page loads the jQuery binds to the id. When you call you Ajax and refresh the content on the page you lose the bind. You have two options to fix this. The first is to call the bind again at the end of the Ajax call. E.g.:

```
$.ajax(function() {
    //... your ajax
    success: function(html) {
        // update page with html
        Rebind();
    }
});

function Rebind() {
    $("#MainContent_previewlist").sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) { }
    });
}
```

If you're dealing with listen events (click, change, update etc.) then you can bind on something that doesn't get updated, such as the document. E.g.:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my-id', function() {
    // do something...
});
```

That bind will persist through an Ajax call, though it isn't recommended you use that method unless you have to because it means the event gets passed through every element in the DOM only gets picked up once it hits the document.

Answer (score 0):

Like Styphon say, try binding to something that does not get reloaded via ajax.
But I recommend you not to bind to document is better bind to 'body' or if you 
have a div that is container bind to that. I improve the question answering a full complete example with the id you used, in this case $(this) is the element you want to make sortable. Try this and let us know:

```
$('body').on('click', '#MainContent_previewlist', function() {
    $(this).sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) { }
    });
});
```